# On the production model ${\bf x} = {\bf C x} + {\bf d}$

Tags: matrices, inverse, economics

> Consider the production model ${\bf x} = {\bf C x} + {\bf d}$ for an economy with two sectors, where
> $$ {\bf C} = \begin{bmatrix} 0.0 &  0.5 \\ 0.6 &  0.2 \end{bmatrix}, \qquad {\bf d} = \begin{bmatrix} 50 \\ 30 \end{bmatrix} $$ Use an inverse matrix to determine the production level necessary to satisfy the final demand.

Answer:

> The necessary production level is $$ {\bf x} = \begin{bmatrix} 110 \\ 120 \end{bmatrix} $$

---

Currently, I am studying for a test and this question and answer were both in the book. However, I can't seem to figure out how they got the answer. I saw an example of a similar problem in Alistair Savage's [solutions](http://alistairsavage.ca/mat1302/exercises/mat1302-input-output-model-exercises-solutions.pdf) to Leontief [input-output model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input%E2%80%93output_model) exercises. For some reason, that method wasn't bringing me to the correct answer. If you could please provide step-by-step instruction on how to do this, it'd be a huge help.

Comment: Which book is that?

Answer (score 0):

Equation: ${\bf x} = ({\bf I} - {\bf A})^{-1} {\bf d}$

`[1  0]       [0   .5]      [1  -.5]                               [1.6  1] minus           =             multiply by ^-1 (inverse)  =  [0  1]       [.6  .2]      [-.6  .8]                              [1.2  2]`

`[1.6  1]      [50]            [110] x(by D)          =  [1.2  2]       [30]            [120]`

**Answer:** [110, 120]

Thorough Explanation Of Similar Problem [Here](http://barnyard.syr.edu/mat183/l32/)!